# Submit form to REST API

Tags: ajax, jquery, rest

Hi i have the following code

```
var dataString = "email=jdoe@example.com&fname=John&lname=Doe&phone=7851233&vid=726&size=2&date=2013-05-28%202:15%20PM&request=Testing%20A%20Message";
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 5000,
    url: "http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php?method=add_reservation",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        alert(data.result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});  
return false;
```

Where basically i would like to submit a piece of string to this URL:
http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php?method=add_reservation

The formatted string (as displayed by firebug) is like this:

http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php?method=add_reservation&email=jdoe@example.com&fname=John&lname=Doe&phone=7851233&vid=726&size=2&date=2013-05-28%202:15%20PM&request=Testing%20A%20Message

When the string is executed via browser (straight copy-pasting) it works perfectly. It displayed the corresponding message.

However, when i execute the code, it always returns error. Does anyone know why this happen?

Cheers,

Comment: Could it have something to do with part of your data being in the url? I.e., move the method=add_reservation into the data string.

Comment: may be something with url encoding?

Comment: @Andy It's a GET request, so he should be able to pass it via the query string, unless the API for that site specifically says not to do that. We need to know more about the "error" that he is receiving.

Comment: @Andy It doesn't work either.  to: Ghazanfar could you be more specific? It is odd since when i test the API from the formatted string (which is the one generated by firebug), it works (and returns some message back).

Comment: What's in `dataString`

Comment: @Aesthete a quick print_r email=jdoe@example.com&fname=John&lname=Doe&phone=7851233&vid=726&size=2&date=2013-05-28%202:15%20PM&request=Testing%20A%20Message

Comment: @Aesthete does it matter even with "%20" encoding? What should i replace it with?

Comment: Guys. You're all getting out of hand. The API is off-site and neither supports JSONP nor CORS. That's where his error comes from - the request just doesn't go through.

Comment: So the script you're running here is not hosted on www.livepicly.com? You're trying to do a cross-site request?

Comment: @Andy: livepicly is a rather big, generic reservation set-up similar in concept to a few UK and US-based APIs. Doubt he owns it - he would not be asking for implementation details otherwise.

Comment: @Andy i am simply (or better yet, the place i work for) is affiliated with the API hoster. So i do not have any kind of access to their server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API in question is not RESTful.

Anyway, your problem is a combination of factors. What it definitely is **NOT** is the API actually throwing an error, as all errors are returned as 200 status codes. (Not RESTful Point #1). So, even if livepicly returned an error, it'd still count as success on jQuery handlers.

In no particular order:

- The API is not throwing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers. It does not support JSONP either. (This can be seen by querying http://www.livepicly.com/app/api.php?method=add_reservation&callback=test ). This will **completely** prevent jQuery from loading **any** data of performing **any** queries to the API due to cross-domain restrictions

That's the only thing that is failing! This is also completely preventing jQuery usage. You'll need to make a choice to go around this one, which may or may not include:

- Proxying the API locally. This is trivial if your webserver is running thanks to Apache or nginx. For Apache, use `ProxyPass` and `ReverseProxyPass` directives using `mod_proxy`, or use a rewrite rule with the `[P,L,QSA]` set of flags. On nginx, use the `proxy_pass` directives. If you have access to neither, proxy it using `curl` through PHP.
- Giving the developers of the API a slap in order for them to simply add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the headers, which will make your call work
- Giving the developers of the API a slap in order for them to support JSONP

Overall, just point them to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer and give them a slap for me. Please?

Comment: after trying out your solution, it actually make sense. I am not sure why it is downvoted. So basically, there is no other wayaround this other than those mentioned by you (Considering i don't have any means to modify the said API)? IMHO, i am discouraged using CURL.

Comment: I should probably open another question about this. But anyway, how do i get the returned message from this URL ??

Comment: @username55: right now, you can't in JS other than by using something server-side to proxy it.

Comment: Also, curl is really easy to use.

Comment: Yea, you are right i have no option other that using CURL. Thx for the hint.

Comment: @username55: No problem. Can you get in touch with the devs to let them know what REST is and how to actually do stuff **properly** while you're there? :-)